# Why postgres logs are visible from a previous, separate docker container which mounted a separate data directory

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerhub

From a blank directory I create a new subdirectory `pg1_data`, and mount it as the data directory of a new container running docker's [official](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) `postgres` image ([version 12, Dockerfile here](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/0d0485cb02e526f5a240b7740b46c35404aaf13f/12/Dockerfile)).

```
user@XXX:~$ ls #(directory is empty)
user@XXX:~$ mkdir pg1_data
user@XXX:~$ docker run --rm -p 55555:5432 --name pg1 --mount 'type=bind,src='/home/user/pg1_data,dst='/var/lib/postgresql/data' postgres
```

The container spins up successfully, the database system accepts connections, and `ls pg1_data` reveals that the postgresql data directory structure has been generated.

Then, lets say I perform `docker stop pg1`, and repeat the first step with a brand new directory and container.

```
user@XXX:~$ mkdir pg2_data
user@XXX:~$ docker run --rm -p 55777:5432 --name pg2 --mount 'type=bind,src='/home/user/pg2_data,dst='/var/lib/postgresql/data' postgres
```

This also works as before, but I see the following output :

```
2019-12-11 04:10:18.441 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.1 (Debian 12.1-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
2019-12-11 04:10:18.442 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2019-12-11 04:10:18.442 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2019-12-11 04:10:18.446 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2019-12-11 04:10:18.469 UTC [54] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2019-12-11 04:10:18 UTC
2019-12-11 04:10:18.476 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

I'm confused as to why postgres in this new container has access to the history of postgres in the old container, with the message "database system was shut down at..." They were separate runs of the `postgres` image, mounting two separate blank data directories. How are these two containers and instances of postgres related? Am I fundamentally misunderstanding how PostgreSQL and/or Docker work?

Comment: why aou think they are related?

Comment: Do you come to this conclusion because of the shutdown/restart lines in you log ? This is a normal init phase for this image when creating a fresh database on an empty data dir. Look at the logs on the first instance, they will be similar. If you want a comprehensive view of how this works, read the [image entrypoint script](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh)

Comment: Many thanks. Yes, I was confused by the shutdown line. It might have been a bit dense of me, but seeing that info upon startup left me wondering if the two containers and/or data directories were somehow sharing state. I will try my best to understand the entry point script you pointed me to!